# SVG: pattern filling is not working with "use"

Tags: svg

I have *icon.svg*:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="icon_page" viewBox="0 0 221 118">
       <pattern id="patt" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="53" height="111"> <image xlink:href="..." x="0" y="0" width="53" height="111"/></pattern>
       <path fill="url(#patt)" d="..."/> 
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

And then I use part of *icon.svg* in html via "use":

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icon.svg#icon_page"></use>
</svg>
```

And pattern filling is not working. Without filling I see figure, but with filling - nothing. If I put svg code direct to html, it work's fine:

```
<svg>
    <symbol id="icon_page" viewBox="0 0 221 118">
       <pattern id="patt" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="53" height="111"><image xlink:href="..." x="0" y="0" width="53" height="111"></image></pattern>
        <path fill="url(#patt)" d="..."></path> 
    </symbol>
    <use xlink:href="#icon_page"></use>
</svg>
```

Have somebody any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try taking the pattern out of the symbol into the parent svg element.

Comment: How do you link the image resource inside the pattern? Is that an external file? What is the relative path to the icon.svg file?

Comment: @ccprog thanks for answer! For pattern image I write absolute URL, this image is in files of my site. I tried use images from other sites - that not working too.
Relative path to the icon.svg is '/assets/images/icon.svg' - and that works, because without pattern I see my image

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for feedback! I tried to do what you say too, but unfortunately it is not working.